# @users variable empty. forget to pass the collection object for will_paginate?

Tags: ruby, variables, factory-bot, railstutorial.org, isnullorempty

**Problem** localhost:3000/users/ won't display

I enter humbly as I am trying to make it through the rails tutorial for the first time. I am in chapter 10 and I have been trouble shooting this for 5 hours. When I attempt to visit localhost:3000/users/ I get an error (I believe this has something to do with factory_girl) that explain that the **@users variable is empty** and that I **forgot to pass a collection object for will_paginate**.

I'm currently at chapter 10, section 10.23 and each time I run:

> $ bundle exec rake db:reset
>
> $ bundle exec rake db:populate
>
> $ bundle exec rake db:test:prepare

I get an error explaining that

> rake aborted! 
>   Factory already registered: micropost

This is my second time trying this chapter as I encountered problems the first time and started from chapter 9. Please help and be clear and detailed when providing directions. I am happy to post whatever files that will be helpful.

Here is my index.html.erb - I save these as HTML, should they be saved as ruby files instead?

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All users</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
  <%= render @users %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

Here is my users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
end

   def new
    @user = User.new
   end

 def index
    @title = "All users"
    @users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end

def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Do more of the things you love!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
    redirect_to users_url
  end

private

    def signed_in_user
      unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
      end
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
    end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your Users controller, make sure you have @users and if you are using will_paginate, make sure you call `.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20]` and in your view, have `<%= will_paginate @users %>`.

Comment: I have changed my users controller line from   atusers = User.paginate(:page => params[:page])  to    atusers = User.paginate(page: params[:page], [per_page: 20] <code> is that what you were suggesting? I am getting a new error now. It is syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tASSOC

Comment: @John what do I type to indicate to this text box that I am entering code?

Comment: See [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) which explains how this site uses markup

Comment: Tommy actually helped me via gchat to fix the problem which was more complete than what was on here.

Answer (score 0):

`/users` should point to UsersController#index. Make sure you are assigning the collection `@users`.

For instance it could look like this at the most basic level:

```
def index
  @users = User.all # not paginated
  @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page]) # paginated
end
```

As far as the test database error, I'm guessing that's because you define a :micropost factory more than once.

Comment: AJcodez, thanks for help. I tried this but it did not work. I knew this was where the issue was so i have been playing with variations to no avail. Where would I find the definition of :micropost factory?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of @user = User.find(params[:id]) this you should use
@users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])